# Population Change

Tags: population, change-detection

I don't know if this site does general human geography, but since it's the only geography site I found this is the question. Population change takes into account 'growth rate' (which includes births and immigration) whilst taking away 'death rate' (which seems to only include death). So does population change take into account emigration (people leaving the country)?

Comment: GIS SE is a **geographic information systems** site, not a general geography site. Questions without a clear GIS component should be asked elsewhere.

Comment: @Vince , Where should this question be asked then?

Comment: Just because they doesn't fit in any other SE site doesn't mean that non-GIS questions are appropriate here. Please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand the purpose and expectations of prior research in GIS SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OECD defines](https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=6638) it as follows:

> The difference between the size of the population at the end and the beginning of a period. It is equal to the algebraic sum of natural increase and net migration (including corrections). There is negative change when both of these components are negative or when one is negative and has a higher absolute value than the other.

Answer (score 2):

Usually demographers use net-migration which is the difference between in and out migration.

Note in many countries (such as the UK) this is a (poor) guess as they don't have an easy way of checking when citizens leave the country or return, and often don't know this for other nationals with visa free travel (e.g. European Union countries).